# How to run the same spider multiple times?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scrapy

I'd like to run the same spider multiple times except I would feed each one a different portion of a generator in hope  that it will scan for the whole thing faster.

I've been thinking about doing something like that :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Spider definition

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider1)  
process.crawl(MySpider1)  
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider1)  
process.crawl(MySpider1)  
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.start()
```

Except I don't know 2 things :

- How to pass an argument to `MySpider1` so I can feed each process a different part from the main generator.
- Would that actually speed up the process ? I'm not sure since I don't know about the internal architecture of this API. Why doesn't a lonely spider already use all the processor ressources given that when I run one it doesn't even sweat. What's the limiting ressource of this system and how many spiders can I run at once ?

Comment: Scrapy already provides a way to do multiple requests in parallel. See [its page on broad crawls](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html) for some things you can try.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex terrific setting the concurrency to 200 has already tripled the throughput, I wonder how far you can push this thing.